# Comment not being added to the database

Tags: python, django, forms, comments

I am working on a movie website with Django and I'm trying to add user comments. Only the registered users should be allowed to comment. I have the following so far:
models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name = "comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.movie.title, self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(label ="", widget = forms.Textarea(
    attrs ={
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Comment here!',
        'rows':5,
        'cols':50
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields =['content']
```

views.py

```
class MovieDetailsView(generic.DetailView):
      model = Movie
      template_name = "details.html"
    
      def comment(request, id):
        movie= Movie.objects.get(id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
          cf = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
          if cf.is_valid():
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(movie = movie, user = request.user, content = content)
            comment.save()
            return redirect(movie.get_absolute_url())
          else:
            cf = CommentForm()
              
      context ={
        'comment_form':cf,
        }
      return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

details.html

```
<form method="POST" action="#" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{comment_form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg">Submit</button>
    <textarea id="text" name="text" class="form__textarea" placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="form__btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

The MovieDetailsView displays the details page of the movie and has a comment section. However, when I submit the comment, it simply displays a white page and this link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/1# . The comment is not saved on the database and I can't seem to find what the issue is. I am also following the example from [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-project-to-create-a-comments-system/) link.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `FormMixin` with `DetailView` - [Using FormMixin with DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview).

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden


class MovieDetailsView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = "details.html"
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('movie_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
        # or
        # return self.object.get_absolute_url()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.movie = self.object
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In the `post()` method, we first check if the user is logged in:

> ```
> if not request.user.is_authenticated:
>     return HttpResponseForbidden()
> ```

In template:

```
<form method="POST" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can remove the `action` attribute, the form will be submitted to  the same page.